# How to copy source code (for Python) into text mate :

Tags: python-3.x

Taking my first programming course in python. Instructions were to: Copy and paste your assembly language source code into your processor document.  Using textmate as my processor document. Not sure how source code is supposed to look. This is what I have :

## Objective: Calculate the area of a triangle

```
>>> base=4
>>> height=3
>>> area=1.0/2.0 * base* height
>>> print("Area is:", area)
Area is: 6.0
```

Is this accurate? I just copied and pasted what I got when I ran it in IDLE for Python

Answer (score 0):

Your code is accurate - for the formula for a triangle, you should know is:

> A = (1/2)*b *h

Therefore the math is correct, henceforth your code is correct. Now - a simpler way to do this is:

```
base, height = 4, 3
area=1/2 * base* height
print("Area is:", area)
```

With python, you can define 2 or more variables on one line, as long as both sides have equal parts.
For Example:

> base, height, width = 4, 3, 2

Having it this way, saves space and is useful for when you want to have return statements in your functions.

```
def main(inp): # For this example we r going to use strings for simplicity sake.
    return inp, inp + "1", inp + "2", inp + "3"
# We return 4 values on one line, where as we cannot use 4 lines of
# return because python will give us an Error
print(main("hello"))
```

## Functions and Classes are part of OOP Programming Btw

See you next time you post,

#### Jerry